# MobaXterm file browser not following terminal after multiple SSH hops

Tags: ssh, terminal, mobaxterm

I'm new to MobaXterm and I have a question about the SSH browser side panel. For my work, I need to connect via ssh to a Server A (login server) and from there ssh again to a Server B (processing server).

Once I login to Server A, I get the SSH Browser showing up, I can explore the file structure, and if I use the "Follow terminal folder" it all works fine and it automatically moves around whenever I use a cd command on the terminal.

However once I further ssh to Server B the side panel browser just stays where I left it on Server A. I can move around on Server B and see all the right directories and files via the terminal commands, but I'd like to have the GUI of the side panel also work.

Is there an option in MobaXterm I need to be aware of that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is marked as "experimental". Expecting a reliability as provided by stable features is not appropriate.

For more details and some possible solutions/workarounds, see [my answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193255/mobaxterm-follow-terminal-folder-doesnt-work/76729721#76729721)

Your specific problem is the *"Issue 4: Sub-Shell opened"* in the answer at the link:

By opening a ssh-connection at the remote *Server A* to the remote *Server B* you open a subshell/program that is a kind of "black box" for  MobaXterm. It will wait until you exit the ssh to *Server B* and then continue to sync the GUI path with the terminal.

---

If your aim for the session is to reach *Server B* you might want to configure *Server A* as *JumpHost*.
Details for this configuration you can find at [my other post at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898440/ssh-sendenv-does-not-work-when-used-with-j-jump-host/75899902#75899902).

This should avoid the problem, as the sftp-connect for the "GUI folder view" feature should also jump to *Server B*, but not stay hanging at *Server A*.